# DNS resolution trouble - nslookup still works

Tags: windows-10, networking, dns, ping

I'm having trouble with my Windows 10 machine. Since 3 hours ago it will no longer try to resolve any DNS queries. Nslookup still works though.

I've flushed the DNS cache, restarted the DNS Client service and done everything else google tells you do. Reset winsock, flush routes, flush DNS, renew DHCP, add a . to the end of queries, ran sfc and dism, rebooted countless times, remade the hosts file, tried different DNS servers, ...

Interestingly when looking at the traffic with Wireshark it seems that only nslookup commands actually generated any traffic, neither ping ,web browsing, nor any other application seemed to trigger any actual name resolution. Pinging IP addresses works without a problem.

I'm at the end of my ropes and so seems google, please help me (I don't want to spend a day reinstalling)

**Edit:** I'm using UnboundDNS internally but when configuring external DNS Servers like Google or Cloudflare resolution still fails. I also tried tethering the LTE connection from my phone via USB - same issue. So I'm pretty certain it's an issue with the Windows installation. Any tips on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: What DNS service are you using?

Comment: I'm using Unbound on my OPNsense. DNS is still working in all other VLANs and using Google or cloudflare DNS yields the same result

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate your using your own dns

Comment: Are you blocking dns ports in any firewalls or router acls on subnets have the issue? Does your DNS server have forwarder hosts set and pointed correctly. Can you run some network commands to check needed ports are accessible from that subnet? Is your default gateway correct and able to get to your DNS server and vice versa in your subnet with issues?

Comment: I can ping internal and external IP addresses fine. Unbound uses 8.8.8.8 as upstream DNS and resolves domains correctly. It is reachable from that subnet. Setting an external DNS on the client results in the same behaviour - external DNS are reachable on 53/UDP. I think this is definitely a client issue, seeing as there are no DNS queries that leave the interface when checking with Wireshark, except when using nslookup. I am monitoring Unbound in my ELK stack and can see the amount of DNS queries from this client sharply dropping after the issue started, with no changes in the network.

Answer (score 0):

Had a surprisingly helpful chat with Microsoft support. Their solution would have been a DNS flush and winsock reset as well. They further advised an in place "upgrade" using the 21H2 iso (same as previously installed).
While the cause is still unknown, this did indeed fix the issue on my install so I'll mark this resolved.